# Difference between model_weights and optimizer_weights in keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

What is difference between model_weights and optimizer_weights in keras. after running following code `model.summary` shows total 9 parameters, which shows in model_weight in `1.h5` file. But optimizer_weight shows total 18 parameters. I used only 1 epoch. Code is following:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 2
epochs = 1

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

#Redistributing data for only two classes
x1_train=x_train[y_train==0]; y1_train=y_train[y_train==0]
x1_test=x_test[y_test==0];y1_test=y_test[y_test==0]
x2_train=x_train[y_train==1];y2_train=y_train[y_train==1]
x2_test=x_test[y_test==1];y2_test=y_test[y_test==1]
X=np.concatenate((x1_train,x2_train,x1_test,x2_test),axis=0)
Y=np.concatenate((y1_train,y2_train,y1_test,y2_test),axis=0)
# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y)

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(2, 2),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(16,16)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
model.summary()
model.save('1.h5')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Model weights** are weights that act on the actual data. 
They will affect the output.

A model alone (without an optimizer) is enough to take an input and produce (predict) an output. The better the model's weights, the better the output.

The whole purpose of training a model is to adjust its weights so it can make good predictions.

An **optimizer**, on the other hand, has no influence on data and predictions.
The role of the optimizer is decide how to change the model's weights during training. I purely for training purposes. The optimizer gets the gradients and decide how to apply these gradients to the model. (Considering learning rates, momentum, etc.)

The optimizer weights are just helpers to improve the adjustment of the model's weights. Once you consider that your model is doing a good job, you can throw the optimizer away.

Comment: But why model_weights are 9 and optimizer_weights are 18 in number in above example. (i am using epoch=1). And suppose i am not using Gradient Based optimizers (using swarm based) then which weight i have to update, model_weights or optimizer_weights??

Comment: I don't know how swarm optimizers work... But I think it takes cares of it's own weights... You can try to increase your model and see what happens to the optimizer weights.

Comment: I understand. The only confusion is, why no of parameters for models_weights and optimizer_weight are different (for above example 9 and 18, i got from model.save)

Comment: Why should they be equal?? It looks like this optimizer has 2 per model's weight. (But check this info).

Comment: from keras documentation i think 9 parameters for loss and 9 for optimizers. line number 69 in <https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L130>